# Is there any difference in meaning between "give me something" and "give with something"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *give me something* and *give with something*? I came across the latter in the 11th episode of the 5th season of *Breaking Bad*. Here is the context:

> Saul: You can't fire up a doob in here! Put that out!
>
> I mean it! Put it out!
>
> Look, Mr. Natural, I'm not gonna let you sabotage this thing.
>
> This guy is not gonna take you. if you show up high,
>
> so stop screwing around, or it's both our asses.
>
> Right. Well, that's a start.
>
> Now **give with** the dope.

Comment: "Give with" does not exist as a phrase in any standard English, AFAIK, or in most dialects. Reading your question, I know that the speaker must be American, but I don't know any closer than that, or precisely what the phrase conveys.

Comment: As an American, I am also not familiar with that usage. I'm not sure if it's real "street language" or just something the TV writers thought would sound like street language. In any case I suspect the intended meaning is closer to "give up the dope" than "give me the dope" (although this is a subtle difference).

Comment: For the record, this was always in question form: What gives with the dope? Here: hand over the dope.(I'm grateful these questions are not about *Deadwood*!)

Comment: @Lambie, "What gives with the dope?" is more like "What is the problem with the dope?" I have only come across "Give with the dope" meaning "hand it over".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "give with something" is a slang idiom. You can find references to it at Google books if you restrict the search to 20th and 21st centuries, with the words "the dope" and "the info" as part of the search.
This is a search with "give with the info":
[Google Books "give with the info"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20with%20the%20info%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&biw=1277&bih=743&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2020&tbm=bks)

It has a demanding tone, though it could be jocular as well. In this use, "dope" probably means "drugs", though it could also mean "information".

There is a reference at McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs:
[McGraw-Hill "give with something"](https://books.google.com/books?id=ss2QboIOsPgC&q=%22give%20with%20the%20money%22&dq=%22give%20with%20the%20money%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN4KXo1v_qAhXLVs0KHRc4CiAQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg)
"to give something to someone, to tell something to someone"
*Come on! **Give with** the money!*
*You had better **give with** the information if you know what's good for you!*

Comment: Yes, this is correct for underworld slang.